# How to use a singleton Session factory in an application with multiple modules

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, thread-safety, sessionfactory

I have a session factory bean defined like this:

```
   <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" 
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test" />
    </bean>
```

I know it's a bit weird that the configuration data is in another file when I can just write it directly here in the bean definition. But it does work.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
     </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

So I'm trying to do some work with the session factory. And It's working. I'm connected to a database, I can use the session factory to save or update to or fetch things from the database. The implementation works.

Now I'm trying to use the same Session factory in another module. I use spring to inject this mySessionFactory bean in it. And it doesn't work.

Then I change the scope of the mySessionFactory bean to "prototype" and everything works well in both modules.

Now I'm guessing that the problem is that when the SessionFactory is a singleton it can't be seen in different modules. Here is an example of a method which uses the SessionFactory:

```
public T fetchById(Class<T> p_type, Long p_id) {

        Session session;
        Transaction transaction;

        T returnT;

        session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        returnT = (T) session.get(p_type, p_id);

        transaction.commit();
        session.close();

        return returnT;

    }
```

I have a couple of these and, again, they all work in the entire application if the mySessionFactory is a prototype, so I don't think it's a dependency issue. But the methods only work in the module where the bean is defined if mySessionFactory is the default singleton.

The Exception I get is:

org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]

My question is what approach to take to use a single instance of the SessionFactory in the entire app. I don't want to create a new SessionFactory every time a method is called.

I don't have a thorough understanding of threads in java so I'm not sure what's the problem. I can only kinda guess. I'm sorry if this question is lacking information.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

two options;

1.hibernate singleton session generator:

use singleton design pattern and create a class with a static method returning a singleton session

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.Session;        
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class HibernateSession {

  static Configuration config;
  static SessionFactory sf;
  static Session session;

  public static Session getSession() {

    if(session==null){

      config=new Configuration();
      sf=config.configure().buildSessionFactory();
      session = sf.openSession();
    }

    return session;
  }
}
```

2.

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class SpringHibernateSession extends HibernateDaoSupport {   

  static SessionFactory sf;
  static Session session;

  public static Session getSession() {

    if(session==null){

         ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("path to the xml file with ur bean id mySessionFactory ");

         sf=(SessionFactory) appContext.getBean("mySessionFactory");
         session=sf.openSession();

    }
    return session;
  }
}
```